# How to use CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent in Python on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, keyboard-events

I have installed the pyobjc (with it Quartz), and I would like to know how one would properly create a keyboard event with CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent? Please? I can not find it at all on the internet, and plus I even have no idea what to import.

***An example code would be nice, telling me what to import and what to put into python***

Does anyone know the required code for the ***FN (FUNCTION KEY)*** in mac for CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
evt = Quartz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, vkey, True)
```

That's all there is to it.

And if you can find examples in C, like [this one in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent), it's trivial to map them to Python.

C:

```
CGEventRef event1, event2, event3, event4;
event1 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)56, true);
event2 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)6, true);
event3 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)6, false);
event4 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent (NULL, (CGKeyCode)56, false);
```

Python:

```
events = [Quartz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 56, True),
          Quartz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 6, True),
          Quartz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 6, False),
          Quartz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 56, False)]
```

As for "what to import", if it's not obvious: `import Quartz`.

If you want to map keys to key codes, the C docs can similarly be translated to Python, but [this simple library](https://github.com/abarnert/pykeycode) wraps up the low-level functions and exposes them to Python.

If you want a nice graphical way to find out what events are being sent through your system, try [Event Taps Testbench](http://pfiddlesoft.com/eventtapstestbench/). If you're on Maverick, you must read the note on Mavericks compatibility or it will not work. Anyway, run it, Add a tap on, e.g., Key Down, Key Up, and Flags Changed, click Current Event or Event History, and watch the key codes fly by.

Comment: So say to double tap the function key, I would do 
`events = [Quartz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 63, True),
           Quartz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 63, False),
           Quartz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 63, True),
           Quartz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 63, False)]`

Comment: @user3151828: Yes, that will double tap the function key. Whatever program you're trying to simulate double-tapping the function key for might actually be watching for flag changes rather than keydowns, or might be looking at a lower level, because that's a pretty odd thing to be watching for…

Comment: This function doesn't work any more on HighSierra. Causes segmentation fault. Are you aware about this?