# trying to simulate fn keys from python in mac

Tags: python, macos, quartz-graphics, quartz-core, pyobjc

I'm trying to simulate double fn keypress on mac to start dictation so far i have read all the docs on SO and applied a few solutions, but all in vain.
I'm trying to open dictation from python code. executed from terminal. So far i'have tried this but with no success.

```
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventPost
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGHIDEventTap

evt = [CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x3f, True), 
        CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x3f, False), 
        CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x3f, True), 
        CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x3f, False)]
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, evt)
```

can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong ?

Comment: Do you use Apple's pre-installed version of Python? As [that seems to be necessary for Quartz.CoreGraphics to work properly](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/notes/quartz-vs-coregraphics.html)..

Comment: Also, after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21397453/4041795) answer, I Googled for `macos CGKeyCode function keys` and I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3202629/4041795) post. Open the file referenced in the answer (`/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h`) I found the corresponding code for `kVK_Function` to be `0x3F` so not `0x3f` (like you seem to be using..?), and I found the `kFunctionKeyCharCode` to be `16`. Not sure if that helps?

Comment: @SB87 i'm using python under virtual environment. Is there any way to access it from there ? yeah i tried that too and with 63 too. but didn't work

Comment: Executing the system Python inside your virtualenv? Guess so.. just execute your scripts via `/usr/bin/python yourpythonscript.py`. Not sure if that is bad design though..

Comment: nope @SB87 this script itself is being executed in virtual environment. i'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

This code working successfully:

```
import Quartz, AppKit

ev = AppKit.NSEvent.otherEventWithType_location_modifierFlags_timestamp_windowNumber_context_subtype_data1_data2_(
     14,
     (0, 0),  # location
     0xa00,  
     0,
     0,
     0,
     8,
     ((0x3f - 128) << 16) | (0xa << 8),
     -1
     )
Quartz.CGEventPost(0, ev.CGEvent())

event = Quartz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 0x3f, True)
Quartz.CGEventSetFlags(event, 0)
Quartz.CGEventPost(Quartz.kCGHIDEventTap, event)
```

The problem was that you didn't specify the flags for the mouse event.The variable "ev" contains all the data where the button will be clicked.